# Xcode 5.1.1 not recompiling subproject

Tags: ios, xcode

I have 2 projects within my workspace (see screenshot), but when I make changes to my secondary project (SDK), it doesn't recompile them. For example if I just write random uncompiling code, it still compiles. Xcode also doesn't break at those breakpoints in the secondary project but it breaks in the primary project. I've tried deleting DerivedData and also cleaning the workspace. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you configured dependencies on the SDK project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the `Utilities` of Xcode if the `.m` files from your secondary project are in the `Target membership`.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I think I just replicate your problem on my side, and found the solution that fixes it. Try going in `Products` > `Scheme` > `Edit Schemes`. Select your primary project scheme in the upper left part of the view, the go in the `Build` section in the left menu. Click on the plus sign and add your secondary project target.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yes they are. That box is checked for the `.m` files for the `SDK` target.

Comment: @quantum I just updated my answers with another possible solution :)

Comment: Oh wait... this is weird. Now when I type random things in the secondary project, it does detect the error and refuses to compile. However when I comment out a large chunk of code that say, displays a `UIAlertView`, that action still happens when I compile and run.

Comment: @quantum Seems like the project isn't recompiling... Try `Product` > `Clean`, this will force a recompiling.